# Expanding or collapsing the download folder

Tags: windows-explorer

I'd would be very helpful if I could somehow expand or collapse the download folder.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Favorites** link is just a shortcut. Clicking on it immediately causes focus to jump to the actual `C:\Users\UserName\Downloads` folder anyway:

[image: 1]

If you create a shortcut to your **Downloads** folder, it will open Explorer directly at that location and moreover the folder will be expanded in the navigation pane as well, which is what you want. (You can also click the *Downloads* link on the Start Menu.)

Comment: So how do you put the username as one of the main folders on the left side though?

Comment: Windows Explorer / Organize button / Folder and search options / Navigation pane section - You'll see 2 checkboxes for *Show all folders* and *Automatically expand to current folder*. Try both and see what sort of behaviour you prefer.